# How do I format numeric data correctly using highchartTable jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

how do I format numeric data correctly using highchartTable jquery plugin?

my code is:

```
$('#articleList').highchartTable();
```

I want this  chart to have numeric data, formatted correctly. Someone help.

my table is as shown below:

```
<table class="table table-striped dataTable" id="articleList" role="grid" aria-describedby="articleList_info">
            <thead>
                <tr role="row">
                    <th class="nowrap sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="articleList" width="10%">
                        County                      </th>
                    <th class="nowrap sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="articleList" width="10%">
                        Financial Year                      </th>
                    <th class="nowrap sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="articleList" width="10%">
                        Budget Type                     </th>
                    <th class="nowrap sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="articleList" width="20%">
                        SubSector                       </th>
                    <th class="nowrap sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="articleList" width="10%">
                        Personnel Emoluments                        </th>
                    <th class="nowrap sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="articleList" width="10%">
                        Goods and Services                      </th>
                    <th class="nowrap sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="articleList" width="10%">
                        Development                     </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="10">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                                <tr class="row0" sortable-group-id="9" role="row">

                    <td class="has-context">
                        NAIROBI                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        2015/2016                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Recurrent                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Education &amp; Research                        </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        100000000                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        20000000                        </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        0                       </td>
                </tr>
                                    <tr class="row1" sortable-group-id="8" role="row">

                    <td class="has-context">
                        NAIROBI                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        2015/2016                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Development                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Education &amp; Research                        </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        0                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        0                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        2000000                     </td>
                </tr>
                                    <tr class="row0" sortable-group-id="7" role="row">

                    <td class="has-context">
                        NAIROBI                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        2014/2015                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Recurrent                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Agriculture                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        500000                      </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        400000                      </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        0                       </td>
                </tr>
                                    <tr class="row1" sortable-group-id="6" role="row">

                    <td class="has-context">
                        NAIROBI                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        2014/2015                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Development                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Agriculture                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        0                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        0                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        1000000                     </td>
                </tr>
                                    <tr class="row0" sortable-group-id="5" role="row">

                    <td class="has-context">
                        KWALE                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        2012/2013                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Recurrent                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Education &amp; Research                        </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        6000000                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        4500000                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                                                </td>
                </tr>
                                    <tr class="row1" sortable-group-id="4" role="row">

                    <td class="has-context">
                        NAIROBI                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        2013/2014                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Development                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Agriculture                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                                                </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                                                </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        15000000                        </td>
                </tr>
                                    <tr class="row0" sortable-group-id="3" role="row">

                    <td class="has-context">
                        NAIROBI                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        2013/2014                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Recurrent                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Agriculture                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        1500000                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        2000000                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                                                </td>
                </tr>
                                    <tr class="row1" sortable-group-id="2" role="row">

                    <td class="has-context">
                        MOMBASA                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        2013/2014                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Development                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Agriculture                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                                                </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                                                </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        5000000                     </td>
                </tr>
                                    <tr class="row0" sortable-group-id="1" role="row">

                    <td class="has-context">
                        MOMBASA                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        2013/2014                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Recurrent                       </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        Agriculture                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        2500000                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        3000000                     </td>
                    <td class="has-context">
                        5000000                     </td>
                </tr>
                                </tbody>
        </table>
```

HighchartTable is a plugin extending highcharts.

Comment: Well... Where is your actual table? You don't present enough information to see any kind of problem.

Comment: am getting my table from DOM.

Comment: table now included @HalvorStrand

Comment: And what in that table do you expect to be on the X-axis, and what on the Y-axis? What series should the graph show?

Comment: axis are determined by the plugin.

Comment: So what problem exactly is it that you are having?

Comment: i need to have comma-separated numeric values

Comment: Can you provide a working example? jsfiddle/codepen/snippet